# Hyphenating modifiers

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

Sometimes it's easy to tell when modifiers need to be hyphenated, such as "time-dependent model", "well-known problem", etc. But sometimes I get confused whether the noun is actually being modified or not. E.g. "the PDZ-domain family" (PDZ proteins are a family containing the PDZ domain).

My lecturer's style guide that I have to follow says that two nouns modifying another noun should be hyphenated (e.g. "liquid-phase hydrolysis").

"PDZ" and "domain" are both nouns like "liquid" and "phase". But are they modifying "family"?

Comment: Yes: "PDZ-domain" is a compound noun, more specifically a compound nominal,  modifying "family".

Comment: but *liquid phase hydrolysis* need not have a hyphen because *liquid* is a perfectly valid adjective and there is really no confusion in meaning to be cleared up. Compare to liquid-liquid phase separation (LLPS).